# What does stop STL from having a "std::deep_ptr"?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

Recently, I came into a situation where I need to copy an object which has a `std::unique_ptr` type member.

```
class A {
/* ... */
std::unique_ptr<A> next_;
};
A a0;
A a1{a0}; 
// compiler error, due to the std::unique_ptr is un-copyable
// but I do need a deep copy!
```

Of course, I could have a `Clone` function in `A` to get me through, but why can't **STL** just have a `deep_ptr` to make my life easier (Change `next_` to `std::deep_ptr<A> next_`).

And IMHO, deep copy is a very common demand among the daily developing life, so why does **STL** lack of such thing `std::deep_ptr`? Does this concept make no sense especially in some high language level(e.g. the level **STL** sits at)?

Comment: I think this is an opinion based question. You can submit a proposal to the C++  committee [here](https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal) if you wish.

Comment: you can wrap the unique_ptr into something that adds the deep copy rather easily, so I guess it wasnt yet considered to be worth the effort to get it into the standard

Comment: There was once a proposal for a [`value_ptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3339.pdf). I guess one reason it hasn't made it into the standard is that it is modelling two incompatible things (a pointer and the value it points to). This affects things like what the meaning of a const value_ptr should be.

Comment: Yes I could, but only after knowing this "deeply" by asking some question. Maybe there are lots of people have same doubt as me and had done tons of studying on it.@Clonk

Comment: I do not get it. If it is unique then the pointer shall not be duplicated into several instances. Even with a plain old pointer gcc will warn you that you have a member of pointer type and that you should disable copy and copy assignment constructor. Why not shared_ptr ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for `value_ptr`.@juanchopanza

Comment: @Francis You could use `std::optional<A>`.

Comment: If it makes "deep" copies then it's not really behaving like a pointer. Maybe a case could be made for a `dynamic_object<T>` that has value semantics but allocates dynamically?

Comment: @super except you can't have `std::optional<A>` as a member of `A`